# How to add a node to xml value in MySql

Tags: mysql, xml

My sample xml value looks like

```
    <food>
     <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
     <price>$5.95</price>
     <description>
     Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
     </description>
     <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
```

I need to add this `<Shop>KFC</Shop>` into the food tag and my output should looks as

```
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>
    Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
    </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
    <Shop>KFC</Shop>
  </food>
```

I tried UpdateXml but behaves differently. Is it possible with the available xml functions
in MySql to do this ?

I am new to MySql. Please help me in figure out this.. 
Thanks in advance..

**UPDATE :**

I tried this code

```
select UpdateXML('<food>
 <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
 <price>$5.95</price>
 <description>
 Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
 </description>
 <calories>650</calories>
</food>', '/food/Shop', '<Shop>KFC</Shop>');
```

and in the second parameter i tried instead `'/food/Shop'` only with `'/food'`
but its not giving the expected results

Comment: Why aren't you posting any code that you've used or tried to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it's a bit tricky to do in MySql. You can achieve that by replacing existing `<calories>` node with `<calories>` + new `<shop>` node.

Use `ExtractValue()` function to get value of existing `<calories>` and construct `<calories>value</calories>` block :

```
set @data = N'<food>
 <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
 <price>$5.95</price>
 <description>
 Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
 </description>
 <calories>650</calories>
</food>';

set @data =UpdateXML(@data, 
                     '/food/calories', 
                     concat(
                        '<calories>',
                         ExtractValue(@data, '/food/calories'),
                        '</calories><Shop>KFC</Shop>'
                        )
                    );
select @data
```

**[Fiddle demo for this answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/42430)**

Similar problem : [MySQL to update an XML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718776/mysql-to-update-an-xml-attribute)