# Insert new XML values in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, xml, marc

Rather than extracting or updating values or attributes of existing `XML` fields in a `MySQL` `column`, I should need to add (`insert`) new `XML` fields, with their own attributes and values. Can UpdateXML be used not just to update existing values, but to `insert` overall new fields and values into an existing `XML` column of a `MySQL table`?

My question is in fact very closely related to the following one:

[MySQL to update an XML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718776/mysql-to-update-an-xml-attribute)